# error in template rendering django and bootstrap

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

I am using a bootstrap index file in the header.html in a django project. Can anyone point out a fix or the easiest method to link the bootstrap file to the static folder. In what places does it need to be done, and how?

Also, for use of bootstrap, could I just use the index file rather than header?

I can see the error (below) but do not know the syntax to fix it. The route i've tried is using Jinja logic and it is on that line that the first error arises. (line 14)

**Current error:**

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\User\Desktop\pythonsite\mysite\aboutme\templates\aboutme\header.html, error at line 14
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
4     <head>
5   
6       <meta charset="utf-8">
7       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
8       <meta name="description" content="">
9       <meta name="author" content="">
10  
11      <title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
12  
13      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
14      <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
15  
16      <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
17      <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
18      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
19      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
20  
21      <!-- Plugin CSS -->
22      <link href="{% static 'vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css' &}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
23  
24      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
```

**Update:**
I changed the static and use of jinja to simply what it was originally in the bootstrap index file: e.g.

```
<link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and this worked in that it ran the webpage, but without CSS>

I still cannot figure out how to link the css from this index page to the templates folder and how/where *what syntax*.

**Current site structure:**

The name of the folder is "aboutme" (name of main app)
Inside it is the static folder.
Inside the static folder, I have dropped the entire contents of the bootstrap download (e.g. the fonts, css and js folders)

I have the templates folder in which I have the aboutme folder and in that is are the header.html and home.html. The header.html is the file that I am using (below), trying to reference the css/js etc so the site looks and displays correctly.

Do I simply use:

```
 <link href="/static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

instead of

```
 <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and do I do this in each case? Or should I be using jinja logic?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere (anywhere) before that, put in

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: it just worked with adding simply the <link href="/static     ......are you saying this is bad practice, or that what you have suggested is necessary. If I removed the <link href="/static in each case, and used load static as you suggested, would that work?

Comment: Just tried it - doesn't work. Would be lovely and simple if it did though!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to load the static, for that we use the following:

**{% load static %}**

To call any static file, it would be like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'FILE PATH' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{% static 'FILE PATH' %}"></script>
```

---

#### Example:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anything</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you have a base template and you want to extend the other templates, you should use the following:

**{% extends 'BASE FILE PATH' %}**

Comment: Is Jinja logic mandatory for use with Django and Python ...or are there other options?